Prove this set is a $C^{*}$-subalgebra of $B(\mathcal{H})$
I am currently trying to establish the result:

If $(A,\Delta)$ is a compact quantum group with Haar state $h \in S(A)$, and $v \in M(\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A)$ is a (right) unitary corepresentation of $(A^{\text{op}},\Delta^{\text{op}})$, then: $$B = \overline{\left\{(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K(\mathcal{H})}} \otimes h)(v(1_{\mathcal{K(\mathcal{H}) }} \otimes a)) \: | \: a \in A^{\text{op}}\right\}} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$ is a $C^{*}$-subalgebra. Here I am using the opposite quantum group ($A^{\text{op}} = A$ as sets with $\Delta^{\text{op}} = \Sigma \circ \Delta$ for $\Sigma: A \otimes A \longrightarrow A \otimes A$ the flip isomorphism) so that I also get a statement about left unitary corepresentations of $(A,\Delta)$.  Note that throughout, $v_{12} = v \otimes 1_A$, $v_{13} = (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K(\mathcal{H})}} \otimes \Sigma)(v_{12})$.

The proof starts off as follows:

Let $a \in A$ and set $x \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ to be $x = (\text{id} \otimes h)(v(1 \otimes a))$.  Then one can easily show that: $$\tag{1}v^{*}(x \otimes 1_A) = (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A}} \otimes h)(v_{13}(1 \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}}(a))).$$  Hence when $a,b \in A$ and $x,y \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ are defined by: $$x = (\text{id} \otimes h)(v(1 \otimes a)), \: \: y = (\text{id} \otimes h)(v(1 \otimes b))$$ using (1) we get: $$y^{*}x = (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h \otimes h)(v_{13}(1 \otimes (b \otimes 1)\Delta^{\text{op}}(a))).$$

I have two questions about this.

How is the identity in (1) shown?  The best I can do is that: $v^{*}(x \otimes 1) = (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A}} \otimes h)(v^{*}_{12}v_{13}(1_{\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}} \otimes 1_A \otimes a))$ after several identifications and computations on elementary tensors.  However from here I get stuck, and infact my answer so far doesn't seem to align with what they are claiming this identity is equal to.

Even if I assume the identity from (1) is true, I can't seem to show the equation for $y^{*}x$.  Perhaps It's just that I am new to tensor products, but these types of identities don't seem obvious at all to show at first glance.  It would be $\textbf{extremely}$ nice if someone could write out the details here so I could at least once see how someone parses a problem like this.


Also once this is proven, I see exactly why this is a $C^{*}$-subalgebra, so I just need assistance with this part of the proof.
Thank you.

So I figured out how to do this after figuring out a similar problem.

Observe that: $$(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)(v_{13}(1 \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}}(a)))$$ $$= (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)(v^{*}_{12}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}})(v)(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}})(1 \otimes a))$$ since $((\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}}))(v) = v_{12}v_{13}$ and $v$ is unitary (so thus the legs of $v$ are also unitaries).  Note also that $v^{*}_{12} = v^{*} \otimes 1$, and $(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)(T \otimes a \otimes 1) = T \otimes a h(1) = T \otimes a$ for elementary tensors $T \otimes a \in \mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A$.  Since slice maps are strictly continuous, we have by strict continuity of the slice map and by the fact that $v^{*} \otimes 1 \in M(\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A \otimes A) = \overline{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A \otimes A}^{\text{strict}}$ that: $$(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)(v^{*} \otimes 1) = v^{*}.$$  Thus, we have: $$(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)(v^{*}_{12}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}})(v)(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}})(1 \otimes a))$$ $$= (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)(v^{*}_{12}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}})(v(1 \otimes a)))$$ $$= v^{*}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)((\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}})(v(1 \otimes a)))$$ $$= v^{*}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \text{id}_A \otimes h)((\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}})(v(1 \otimes a)))$$ $$v^{*}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes [(\text{id}_A \otimes h) \circ \Delta^{\text{op}}])(v(1 \otimes a))$$ $$= v^{*}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h(\cdot)1_A)(v(1 \otimes a))$$ since the Haar state for the opposite quantum group satisfies the left/right invariance condition: $$(\text{id}_A \otimes h) \circ \Delta^{\text{op}}(a) = (h \otimes \text{id}_A) \circ \Delta^{\text{op}}(a) = h(a)1_A \: \: \forall a \in A.$$ However then we see: $$v^{*}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h(\cdot)1_A)(v(1 \otimes a))$$ $$= v^{*}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h \otimes \text{id}_A) \circ (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \text{id}_A \otimes 1)(v(1 \otimes a))$$ $$= v^{*}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h \otimes \text{id}_A)(v(1 \otimes a) \otimes 1)$$ $$= v^{*}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h)(v(1 \otimes a)) \otimes 1$$ $$=v^{*}(x \otimes 1)$$ as claimed.
I believe there is actually a typo in the paper this came from, as I believe the identity should actually be: $$y^{*}x = (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h \otimes h)(v_{13}(1 \otimes (b^{*} \otimes 1)\Delta^{\text{op}}(a))).$$  Indeed, we see that: $$(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h \otimes h)(v_{13}(1 \otimes (b^{*} \otimes 1)\Delta^{\text{op}}(a)))$$ $$= (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h \otimes h)(v_{13}(1 \otimes b^{*} \otimes 1)(1 \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}}(a))$$ $$= (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h \otimes h)((1 \otimes b^{*} \otimes 1)v_{13}(1 \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}}(a))$$ since $v_{13}= (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Sigma)(v \otimes 1)$ (for $\Sigma$ the flip isomorphism of $A \otimes A$).  Now, it's clear that $(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes \Sigma)(T \otimes a \otimes 1)$ commues with $1 \otimes b^{*} \otimes 1$, so again by strict continuity of everything we get $v_{13}$ commuting with $1 \otimes b^{*} \otimes 1$.  However $\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h \otimes h = (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h) \circ (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)$ so we get: $$(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h \otimes h)((1 \otimes b^{*} \otimes 1)v_{13}(1 \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}}(a))$$ $$=(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h) \circ (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)((1 \otimes b^{*} \otimes 1)v_{13}(1 \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}}(a))$$ $$= (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h)((1 \otimes b^{*})(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}) \otimes A} \otimes h)((1 \otimes b^{*} \otimes 1)v_{13}(1 \otimes \Delta^{\text{op}}(a)))$$ $$=(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h)((1 \otimes b^{*})v^{*}(x \otimes 1))$$ from 1.  Thus we get: $$(\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h)((1 \otimes b^{*})v^{*}(x \otimes 1))$$ $$= (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h)((1 \otimes b^{*})v^{*})x$$ $$= (\text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})} \otimes h)(v(1 \otimes b))^{*}x$$ $$=y^{*}x$$ since states of $C^{*}$-algebras are $*$-preserving.  The above line is exactly why I think there is a typo in the paper, since otherwise you are stuck with a $v(1 \otimes b^{*})$ when factoring out the adjoint.

